# What is Patent #100? Are all numbers used?

Tags: usa, history

Google has a patent service (if you don't already know).  Here are some example URLs:

- http://www.google.com/patents/US1
- http://www.google.com/patents/US99
- http://www.google.com/patents/US101
- http://www.google.com/patents/US43211

You can type pretty much any number they've gotten to, that they've used so far.  However I can't find anything on patent 100.  Why?  What is it?  I also can't find it on a regular search.

404 Not Found http://www.google.com/patents/US100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/issuyear.htm:

> The current patent numbering system began with a patent issued on July 13, 1836. Prior to that date, 9,957 patents had been issued.

These 9,957 patents before patent [US1](http://google.com/patents/US1) include the first U.S. patent, which was numbered [X1](http://google.com/patents/USX1) or X000001. It was granted on July 31, 1790 to [Samuel Hopkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Hopkins_%28inventor%29).

Still from http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/issuyear.htm:

> Some numbers within a series may be unused. Therefore, the number of patents granted during a year cannot be determined by simply subtracting the number of the first patent issued in one year from the number of the first patent issued in the next year.

Therefore I guess there is no patent #100 in the current numbering system. There doesn't seem to be one either in the previous numbering system. Patents 100 and X100 cannot be found from [USPTO full-page images database](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/patimg.htm).

Experience shows that you can get a 404 from Google Patents while an application already exists and can be found elsewhere (USPTO Public Pair, Espacenet...), probably because of database updates.